# Converting positive numeric values into a factor R

Tags: r, dplyr

A subset of my dataframe is

```
> IntensityIndex
  Individual  X1980LLTper X1981LLTper X1982LLTper
       1      4789.337905   15.012398   19.099139
    1201        32.470518    0.000000   27.880136
    2231         0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
    3331        20.200198  964.691700    4.367191
    8545        40.367227   11.844057    2.227061
   10031        10.425561   68.817743   29.815259
   13543        65.883538  364.601077   16.630508
   15843         7.161902    0.000000 1909.549849
   23349     18704.452730    0.000000    0.000000
   24901         3.347454    0.000000   72.299520
   25901       822.430973  414.693913 3265.319947
   50439        15.058856   11.638729    0.000000
```

I need to convert all values >0 into a numeric variable of 1. So I want to achieve:

```
Individual  X1980LLTper X1981LLTper X1982LLTper
       1      1            1           1
    1201      1       0.000000         1
    2231  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
  etc.
```

I would then use these as dummy variables with the factor() function in a further analysis.

Please keep in mind that this data exists as part of a larger dataset ranging from 1980 till 2012. eg:

```
$X1980LLTper, $X1981LLTper, ... $X2012LLTper
```

as well as a range of individual variables (income, age, sex, etc)

I would be appreciative if any solutions would contain a concise code that would allow me to append the matrix of generated dummy variables to my larger dataset.

Comment: @Sotos, I got this:
 'Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, IntensityIndex[, -1] > 0, value = 1) : 
  unsupported matrix index in replacement'

Comment: you can also try `IntensityIndex[,-1] <- ifelse(IntensityIndex[,-1] > 0, 1, 0)`

Comment: @MarcelG Thanks mate, did the trick! :) Cheers

Comment: yeah...didn't test before posting :)... `df1[,-1][df1[,-1] > 0] <- 1`

Comment: @Sotos Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already answered the question in the comments, but can you accept this answer so others know there is an answer? Some people in this [Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) suggest to a post your solution in the comment as an answer.

You can do this by:
`IntensityIndex[,-1] <- ifelse(IntensityIndex[,-1] > 0, 1, 0)`

Or you can use the suggestion of @Sotos `IntensityIndex[,-1][IntensityIndex[,-1] > 0] <- 1`

Comment: You can change `df1` to the actual `IntensityIndex` name If you want

Comment: @Sotos agreed, this makes the answer more consistent.